# Получить значение, взятое из input

Tags: javascript, html

Как получить текст из поля input? В моём случае выдаёт пустую строку

```
var login=document.getElementById("login").value;
var CheckLogin=document.getElementById('Checklogin');
var button=document.getElementById("start");

function checkLengthLogin(){
    console.log(login);
}

button.addEventListener('click', checkLengthLogin); 



<div id="register">
    Enter your login: <textarea type="text" id="login"></textarea><br>
    Re-Enter your login: <input type="text" id="Checklogin">
    <button id="start">Register!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `var CheckLogin=document.getElementById('Checklogin').value;`

Answer (score 1):

не смотря на странность вашего кода, вот решение

```js
var login=()=>document.getElementById("login").value;
var CheckLogin=document.getElementById('Checklogin');
var button=document.getElementById("start");

function checkLengthLogin(){
    console.log(login());
}

button.addEventListener('click', checkLengthLogin);
```

```html
<div id="register">
    Enter your login: <textarea type="text" id="login"></textarea><br>
    Re-Enter your login: <input type="text" id="Checklogin">
    <button id="start">Register!</button>
</div>
```

и да, это плохой код

Comment: Я новичок. Мне пока можно)